# After AIDE check, the buff/cache is full in CENTOS7

Tags: centos7, aide

I have configured AIDE (Advanced Intruder Detection Environment) in my Centos7 VPS which has 2GB of RAM.

After running AIDE --check I get the desired or the intended result.

But when I check the available RAM the following is the result I get. The buff/Cache is almost full. Why is this happening?

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1.8G        249M        100M        9.8M        1.5G        1.4G
Swap:          511M         15M        496M
```

Edit--

I want to know whether other AIDE users are experiencing the same issue or not. Does the memory used by the cache/buffer affect the overall server performance. I am using this VPS as a web server only.

Comment: Its evident that the cache memory is being used by the OS to store the recently read files, with AIDE this must be the case too. I am just curious if other AIDE users are experiencing the same or whether it is just me.

Comment: Probably everyone does. But it doesn't really matter much, as the linked question explains.